# unable to use 'call' method in lagom

Tags: lagom

I am experimenting with Lagom to check how `call`, `pathCall` and `namedCall` are invoked. I am following lagom's tutorial. I created a new service and opened url using following urls but I get error

URL used (I expect to see hello2 response)

```
http://localhost:9000/
```

Error

```
GET\Q/stream\EService: hello-stream (http://0.0.0.0:58322)
2GET\Q/api/hello/\E([^/]+)Service: hello (http://0.0.0.0:57797)
3POST\Q/api/hello/\E([^/]+)Service: hello (http://0.0.0.0:57797)
**4POST\Q/hello2\EService: hello (http://0.0.0.0:57797)**
```

I have done following steps

After downloading template (see https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/IntroGetStarted.html), I have changed the code to add a new service call (called hello2).  Following is teh code I have added in HelloService.scala

```
named("hello")
      .withCalls(
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", hello _),
        pathCall("/api/hello/:id", useGreeting _),
        call(hello2) //added this line in default template.
      )
```

I have defined hello2 as (in HelloService.scala)

```
def hello2: ServiceCall[String, String]
```

The code in HelloServiceImpl.scala is

```
override def hello2 = ServiceCall {
    Future.successful("Hello2")
  }
```

Questin 1 - What is the mistake (I guess I am not invoking the service correctly from the browser)?

Comment: You should only have one question per post (See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post), I've answered your first one. Can you break the second one out into a separate question please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, "I guess I am not invoking the service correctly from the browser", do you mean you're just navigating to the URL in your browser? If so, this won't work because hello2 is defined as a POST endpoint and your browser will be sending a GET request.

hello2 is defined as a POST endpoint because in your ServiceCall definition it takes a request message. (See https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ServiceDescriptors.html for more info.)

If you change the request message type from `String` to `NotUsed` then Lagom should start generating a GET endpoint instead.

Comment: thanks. Made this change `def hello2: ServiceCall[NotUsed, String]` and following worked `http://localhost:9000/hello2`